# XSLT: Specific tag placement

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

Here is a snippet from my input XML file:

```
<p>List:
<ul>
<li>a</li>
<li>b</li>
<li>c</li>
</ul>This is a list</p>
```

I need to to display this in my output XML as:

```
<p>List:</p>
<ul>
<li>a</li>
<li>b</li>
<li>c</li>
</ul><p>This is a list</p>
```

I did this by simply hardcoding the `p` tag which did not prove beneficial in the longer run. Suppose there's no `"This is a list"`, then it gave me this:

```
<p>List:</p>
<ul>
<li>a</li>
<li>b</li>
<li>c</li>
</ul><p></p>
```

The file is valid but I don't need an empty `p` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">

<xsl:template match="p">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p/text()">
    <p><xsl:value-of select="."/></p>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ul">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the one that uses `xsl:for-each-group`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"></xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="node()" group-adjacent="if (self::text()) then 1 else 0">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key()">
                <p><xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/></p>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```